# Plot + change font size in R

Tags: r

I want to reduce the label expression `"hola"` in this instruction:

```
axis(1, at = c(32.65), labels = expression("hola"))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: may be with the `cex.axis` parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the argument `cex.axis`. This is a scaling value relative to 1, thus values `<1` reduce the font size, and values `>1` increase the font size:

```
plot(1:50)
axis(1, at = c(32.65), labels = expression("hola"), cex.axis=2)
axis(1, at = c(45), labels = expression("hola"), cex.axis=0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `cex.axis` to change the label size.

For instance:

```
axis(1, at = c(32.65), labels = expression("hola"), cex.axis=0.8)
```